# convert double into int

Tags: java, casting, integer, double

I have following `double` value:
`8.943` need to convert(cast) into `int` e.g: `8.943*1000000 = 8943000`
required value --> `8943000`

please help!

thanks.

Comment: You seem to already know what you're trying to do. Or is there something more you're looking for, like using `(int)` cast?

Comment: I dont know what happened to me i was doing this `((int)arg*oneMillion)` for that, i got wrong output, i forgot to use `(int)(arg*oneMillion)` well thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
double myDouble = 8.943
int myInt = (int) (myDouble * 1000000)
```

Using (int) casts the double into an int

Comment: I dont know what happened to me i was doing this `((int)arg*oneMillion)` for that, i got wrong output, i forgot to use `(int)(arg*oneMillion)` well thanks for help!